# App crashes when logging in

Tags: android, authentication, nullpointerexception

I'm working on an app which has `user login` screen. Whenever I am clicking on the **Signin** button, the app crashes. As, I am new to android app development consisting of login screen type applications; hence not able to fix the error. Please look to the error and help me fixing it. Attaching `LoginActivity.java` file:

```
public class LoginActivity1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button bLogin;
// Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://13.228.8.241/phonegap/api/login.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_login1);
        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        bLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);
        bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        String username= user.getText().toString();
        String password=pass.getText().toString();
           switch (v.getId()) {
               case R.id.signin:
                   new AttemptLogin().execute(username,password);
               case.default: break;
           }
    }
    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        /** * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog * */
        boolean failure = false;
        @Override protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity1.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            int success;
            String username = args[0];
            String password = args[1];
            try { List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest( LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Successfully Login!", json.toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity1.this,ContentSecond.class);
                   startActivity(i);
                   finish();
                   return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
                else{
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (message != null){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity1.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The **logcat** is:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                                                                             Process: com.adani.animon.adani, PID: 8678
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
>                                                                                 at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
>                                                                                 at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                                                                                 at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   com.adani.animon.adani.LoginActivity1$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity1.java:76)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.adani.animon.adani.LoginActivity1$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(LoginActivity1.java:53)
>                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
>                                                                                 at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>                                                                                 at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>       08-17 14:58:23.089 8678-8842/com.adani.animon.adani D/libEGL: eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xe0362834
>       08-17 14:58:23.089 8678-8678/com.adani.animon.adani D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
>       08-17 14:58:23.099 8678-8678/com.adani.animon.adani E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.adani.animon.adani.LoginActivity1 has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{c367582 V.E......
>   R......D 0,0-668,232} that was originally added here
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:599)
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:326)
>                                                                                at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:109)
>                                                                                at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:505)
>                                                                                at
>   com.adani.animon.adani.LoginActivity1$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(LoginActivity1.java:62)
>                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:604)
>                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:551)
>                                                                                at
>   com.adani.animon.adani.LoginActivity1.onClick(LoginActivity1.java:45)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5714)
>                                                                                at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
>                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22589)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: There is some error in doInBackground() method. The app is crashing due to null object. Try to debug the code with breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your concern brother but i'm not that good with debugging. I've tried many codes to solve this but failed.

Comment: You have to do debugging in order to know where is the error. Search SO or google about debugging

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response is null

Message says: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference

You should add null check before accessing variable named "json"

Comment: Thanks but how to add null check before accessing the variable?

Comment: you must write `if (json != null)` before executing

`success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);`

Comment: Okay. But now it' showing error in line `if(success==1)` as Variable 'success' might not have been initialised although it is initialised.

Comment: Initialised `int success==0` and tried using `if (json != null)` before `success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS)` and tried running app but  still getting the same logcat.